# How to modify default countdown timer?

Tags: javascript

Based on this project (https://codepen.io/mattlitzinger/pen/ysowF), this project is very wonderful but I want to modify this code (target date with specific date). This js code

```
    var target_date = new Date().getTime() + (1000*3600*48); // set the countdown date
    var days, hours, minutes, seconds; // variables for time units

    var countdown = document.getElementById("tiles"); // get tag element

    getCountdown();

    setInterval(function () { getCountdown(); }, 1000);

    function getCountdown(){

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

days = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 86400) );
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;

hours = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 3600) );
seconds_left = seconds_left % 3600;

minutes = pad( parseInt(seconds_left / 60) );
seconds = pad( parseInt( seconds_left % 60 ) );

// format countdown string + set tag value
countdown.innerHTML = "<span>" + days + "</span><span>" + hours + "</span><span>" + minutes + "</span><span>" + seconds + "</span>"; 
     }

    function pad(n) {
return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;
    }
```

And Then I want to set target date to March 5, 2019 23:59:59. I know, I must to modify this code, but I'm new of this js code.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct you just need to change the target date value to

`var target_date = new Date(2019,2,5,23,59,59,0).getTime();`

check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qgyELL

You can always refer to documentations for more help, the format that Date takes is `new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`.

documentation link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thank you very much @prakash-saripaka ...How about set GMT Time +7 ?

Comment: yes @FranksyeSipangkar you can add +7 hours to target time by converting it to milliseconds.just try to edit the code in codePen i am sure u'll be able to achieve it.
BTW best of luch for 6th March. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the target value in the following way:

```
new Date("Mar 5, 2019 23:59:59").getTime();
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp